# Python file-IO and zipfile. Trying to loop through all the files in a folder and then loop through the texts in respective file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, nested-loops, python-zipfile

Trying to extract all the zip files and giving the same name to the folder where all the files are gonna be.
Looping through all the files in the folder and then looping through the lines within those files to write on a different text file.
This is my code so far:

```
#!usr/bin/env python3
import glob
import os
import zipfile

zip_files = glob.glob('*.zip')
for zip_filename in zip_files:
    dir_name = os.path.splitext(zip_filename)[0]
    os.mkdir(dir_name)
    zip_handler = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, "r")
    zip_handler.extractall(dir_name)

path = dir_name
fOut = open("Output.txt", "w")

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    for line in filename.read().splitlines():
        print(line)
        fOut.write(line + "\n")
fOut.close()
```

This is the error that I encounter:

```
for line in filename.read().splitlines():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: `filename` is a string. instead of `read()`ing the string, you need to open the file and then read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the file and also join the path to the file, also using splitlines and then adding a newline to each line is a bit redundant:

```
path = dir_name
with open("Output.txt", "w") as fOut:    
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        # join filename to path to avoid file not being found
        with open(os.path.join(path, filename)):
            for line in filename:
                fOut.write(line)
```

You should always use `with` to open your files as it will close them automatically. If the files are not large you can simply `fOut.write(f.read())` and remove the loop.

You also set `path = dir_name` which means path will be set to whatever the last value of `dir_name` was in your first loop which may or may not be what you want. You can also use `iglob` to avoid creating a full list `zip_files = glob.iglob('*.zip')`.

Comment: No worries just make sure `dir_name` is what you think it is.

Comment: The thing is I have got zero experience with python before this. I am doing this as an assignment for my survey of programming language class. I've only got a week and I am trying to find help as I go.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala If they are god and it works like a charm, why did you not accept the answer?

Comment: must have forgotten. I was relatively new to stackoverflow back then. Done!